# Default Message Converters in Spring MVC 5

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, converters

I'm trying to understand why my `spring v.5.0.4-RELEASE` doesn't load correctly the default message converters.
I removed all declaration from my servlet.xml and I was expecting to find all the default converters correctly loaded from `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` inside spring, but I get only the following 4:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@35ca138b
org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@2b755f0d
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter@74f5d717
org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@6982b849
```

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up understanding the issue was caused by the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
```

This was overriding the Spring defaults and publishing the four converters listed in my question.
Solution was to place the converters I was looking for, under the bean like follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                        <property name="autoDetectFields" value="true" />
                        <property name="autoDetectGettersSetters" value="false" />
                        <property name="objectMapper">
                            <bean class="com.mypackage.CustomMapper" />
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"> 
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>text/html</value>
                     </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The configuration placed under the `annotation-driven` was totally ignored:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
    ...
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue trying to migrate from Spring 4 to 5.
Any idea why the `mvc:message-converters` is ignored?