# `mvc:message-converters` ignored in Spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We used to have the following configuration to customize our message converters in Spring 4:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper"/>
      </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But after migrating to Spring 5, the above configuration has lost any effect (the default message converters take place).

If I define the bean explicitly, it works:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
          <property name="objectMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
              <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
          </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttannotation-drivenpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Any idea why the `mvc:message-converters` tag stopped working?

ps. While debugging the issue I also noticed several instances of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` being instantiated in all cases, even though I would expect them to be a singleton. The latter significantly obscures debugging, since I'm not sure which is the *right* one to attribute message converters to to investigate.

pps. Another report of this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156186/657723

Comment: *While debugging the issue I also noticed several instances of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`* which is your actual problem. The `mvc:message-converters` still works but due to that there are multiple instances of the bean the one in use doesn't use it. You need to figure out where the other one is coming from.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the advice. However, apparently multiple instances are expected, since they might come both from application context and servlet contexts.

Comment: Only the one that is in the context used by the `DispatcherServlet` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `mvc:message-converters` was overridden by another, empty `mvc:annotation-driven` which happened to be unnoticeably included down the chain of child xml inclusions.

In any case, the major problem was the silent override, which should have better be an error.